# Validar formulario de conversión de moneda con Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, laravel

Tengo un conversor de monedas, con sus dos input respectivos. Además tengo 2 valores pasados por bbdd (min y max) y necesito validar que cuando se ingrese en un input un valor menor al del min se ponga en rojo el input y deshabilite el boton y lo mismo con el valor max. Tengo conocimientos de como hacer la validación del color del input y el boton pero no de como hacer para los valores.

Código:

```js
var dolar = document.getElementById("usd");

      function vesDolares(valNum) {
        document.getElementById("usd").value=valNum * 0.000050;
      }

      function dolaresVes(valNum) {
        document.getElementById("ves").value=valNum * {{ $post->tasa }};

        if(dolar < {{ $post->min }} || dolar > {{ $post->max }}){
          $('.div').addClass('input-group has-error has-feedback');
          $('#boton').attr("disabled", true);
        }else{
          $('.div').addClass('input-group');
          $('#boton').attr("disabled", false);
        }

      }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-6 border-r">
  <div class="input-group div">
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="usd" name="crypto-buy-usd" placeholder="0,00" oninput="dolaresVes(this.value)" onchange="dolaresVes(this.value)">
    <div class="input-group-addon font-w600">USD</div>
  </div>
</div>


<input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="ves" name="crypto-buy-btc" placeholder="0.00" oninput="vesDolares(this.value)" onchange="vesDolares(this.value)">
<div class="input-group-addon font-w600">VES</div>

<button id="boton">Boton</button>
```

Comment: Te refieres en tiempo real ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenias varios problemas en tu código:

- Para acceder al valor del input `'usd'` debes usar `dolar.value` no solo `dolar`.
- La función `addClass()` se emplea para agregar una clase, no para cambiarla por completo, para remover una clase puedes emplear `removeClass()`.
- Respecto a la lógica del mínimo y el máximo puedes hacerlo por complemento; si el valor de dolar esta entre este rango se remueve la clase `has-error has-feedback`, de otro modo se agrega.

Luego el código queda funcionando de la siguiente forma:

```js
var dolar = document.getElementById("usd");
 var taza = 19887.00;
 var min = 100.00;
 var max = 100000.00;

  function vesDolares(valNum) {
    document.getElementById("usd").value=valNum / taza;
  }

  function dolaresVes(valNum) {
    document.getElementById("ves").value=valNum * taza;

    if(dolar.value > min && dolar.value < max){
      $('.div').removeClass('has-error has-feedback');
      $('#boton').attr("disabled", false);
    }else{
      $('.div').addClass('has-error has-feedback');
      $('#boton').attr("disabled", true);
    }

  }
```

```css
.has-error{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-6 border-r">
  <div class="input-group div">
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="usd" name="crypto-buy-usd" placeholder="0,00" oninput="dolaresVes(this.value)" onchange="dolaresVes(this.value)">
    <div class="input-group-addon font-w600">USD</div>
  </div>
</div>


<input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="ves" name="crypto-buy-btc" placeholder="0.00" oninput="vesDolares(this.value)" onchange="vesDolares(this.value)">
<div class="input-group-addon font-w600">VES</div>

<button id="boton" disabled>Boton</button>
```

Para este ejemplo el mínimo es 100 y el máximo es 100000, luego puedes reemplazar los valores.

De esa forma ya funciona como esperas, saludos.

Comment: muchas gracias!!!